# pop up display near to its parents with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, position

I have some images in my web page, and I want to display a pop up  when the user hover the mouse near each image, and when the user move the mouse elsewhere, the pop up disappears

I see this functionality in a lot of site but I don't know how I can do it
I saw jquery UI but the dialog doesn't match to my goal

do you have any idea

I just tested that but no result :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>title</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#hover1").mouseenter(function() {
   $("#content").fadeIn('fast');
});

$("#hover1").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#content").fadeOut('slow');
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="hover1">
   Hover here!
</p>
    <div id="content" style="display:none">
   Content here!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

thank you

Comment: This is troubleshooting site, not a script provider. So please post some script if you tried.

Comment: sincerly, I have not tried, but I say this : [http://jqueryui.com/dialog/]  but I don't like it, because I see in a lot of sites popups that open next to their parent and they disappear when the user move elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

wrap image with relative container and put inside absolute container (popup), show him (display:block; from display:none;) onbly then wrap container is hovered. do not forget to set z-index for popup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `jQuery` `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions:

```
<p id="hover1">
   Hover here!
</p>

<div id="content" style="display:none">
   Content here!
</div>

$("#hover1").mouseenter(function() {
   $("#content").fadeIn('fast');
});

$("#hover1").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#content").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SzgqR/

**Documentation**

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

**Edit**

Remember to include `jQuery` into your page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for your proposal but it doesn't work for me, : see the question  I edited the post

Comment: @simonTifo you have not included the jquery library.

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I uncluded it but no result when I hover the "Hover here !"

Comment: @simonTifo take a look at the JSFiddle I provided and ensure jQuery library is included on the left hand side.  It shows the demo I provided working.

Comment: @simonTifo did you manage to fix this? I have tested the fiddle it works for me in IE and Chrome.